# break dataframe into separate datafarmes or list wrt to same row values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

i want this dataframe in separate datafarmes or list based on NAME which is dynamic (S N, H H, L S, O S.....) , i tired by groupby but there doesnot seems to be any way to break with same row values in different frames.

```
NAME    VALUES
0      S N     1.74
1      S N    24.97
2      S N    10.49
3      H H    11.17
4      S N     5.99
5      H H     2.95
6      H H    16.13
7      H H     2.06
8      H H     6.87
9      S N     2.54
10     H H    19.87
11     H H    48.00
12     H H    11.91
13     S N     4.56
14     S N    15.17
15     O S     4.59
16     H H     4.80
17     H H     7.89
18     H H    22.22
19     H H     6.84
20     S N    12.43
21     H H     9.92
22     H H    31.73
23     S N     6.61
24     S N     5.89
25     H H    12.76
26     H H     4.26
27     H H    20.01
28     S N    30.46
29     S N     5.98
30     S N    15.56
31     D L    61.71
32     H H     7.13
33     H H     1.97
34     H H    47.93
35     O S    16.19
36     H H     1.88
37     S N     5.38
38     H H      NaN
39     H H     9.87
40     H H    44.02
41     H H    17.85
42     H H    23.87
43     S N    11.32
44     H H    10.04
45     S N     1.10
46     L S    23.85
47     S N    12.84
48     H H     0.06
49     O S     0.49
50     O S     0.00
51     H H     0.04
```

Dataframe 1

```
Name Values
SN   1.74
SN   24.97
```

Dataframe 2

```
Name Values
HH   1.74
HH   24.97
```

Dataframe 3

```
Name Values
L S   1.74
L S   24.97
```

Etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can convert column to numpy array and then use `numpy.unique()` to keep a list with only one copy of each unique value in Name. Then you can iterate through this list and take only relevant rows from dataframe using `dataframe.loc`

(I still think groupby solution is the easiest, but if you want to avoid it - the above is another option)